# Error while creating runtime object

Tags: c#

```
String commClass = "ClassA";
Assembly objAssembly = Assembly.Load("DemoClassLibrary");
IA iFace = (IA)objAssembly.CreateInstance(commClass);
iFace.run();
```

I am getting null in iFace variable

```
public interface IA
{
    void run();
}
public class ClassA : IA
{
    string str = string.Empty;

    public void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        Logger.Logger.CreateLog(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
    }
}
```

above is the class declaration by the namespace DemoClassLibrary

can u please help me out..

thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could well be the problem:

> above is the class declaration by the namespace DemoClassLibrary

You need to pass a *fully-qualified* name to `Assembly.CreateInstance`, so you may want:

```
String commClass = "DemoClassLibrary.ClassA";
```